# Shared required module using fork in node

Tags: node.js, fork

i have a module(like internal API) which creates a connection to DB and makes calls to DB. I want to use it in a node project, but i am using the **fork** to create child process. I want this module initialized only once in the parent process and somehow to share it with the other processes(because i dont want each time initialized in each child process). I am trying to use **child.send({..})** method but it is not working. The issue with **child.send({..})** is that when i am sending the object as a message will not deliver any functions. Is any way the child processes have access in parent modules or to deliver functions via message?

Comment: Does initialising it really cost that much?

Comment: @DominicTobias Basically, the main reason that i dont want to init it again is that sometimes(i am using couchbase for DB) the connection to DB returns errors. So i am trying to initialize the module only once at the beginning of node process. So if i get an error, i will get it at this moment.

Comment: @DominicTobias  The main issue using child.send({..}) is that when i am sending the object as a message will not deliver any functions